# can we have C++ type enum in java?

Tags: java, oop, enums

hi in C++ we can have enum of follwoing type:

```
enum e_acomany {    Audi=4,     BMW=5,      Cadillac=11,    Ford=44,    Jaguar=45,      Lexus,      Maybach=55,     RollsRoyce=65,      Saab=111  };
```

can we have the similar enum in java. This question might seems childish but i am new to java enum please give me the answer and also provide some links to example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define enum values with associated numbers:

```
public enum Company {

    AUDI(4), BMW(5), CADILLAC(11), FORD(44), JAGUAR(45), ...;

    private final int id;

    private Company(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

You can then write your own method to convert an `id` to a `Company` value. But fundamentally enums are pretty different in Java to C++, and you may well *not* want to use them in exactly the same situations.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much yes. yet the syntax is a bit different. look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, enums exist in Java (Since version 5 I believe)

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: i dont think this is answer to my question. I know enum exists in java but i want the above enum implemented in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Define your enum this way:

```
public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Color carColor = RED;
if ( carColor == RED )
    carColor = BLUE;
```